# running time for an e bike on a fully charged battery

Tags: batteries, speed

how much time a battery(48 V 35 Amp hr) can drive an electric cycle(weighing 80 kg) powered by a 150 Watts permanent magnet DC motor at an average speed of 20 km/hr.

Comment: What is the average duty cycle of the motor?

Comment: Theoretically there are 48×35=1680Wh in your battery. If the gearing and power supply of the bike is such that the motor is actually loaded at 150W, then you have 1680/150=11.2hr running time.

Comment: BUT IT WILL VARY WITH THE WEIGHT OF THE PERSON DRIVING THE CYCLE RIGHT..?

Comment: The maximum power will be affected by drag , load or acceleration and may affect speed.  Since weight affects acceleration more than wind drag, this will affect run time more. If steady speed, weight will not be a factor

Comment: i want to know how weight will affect the running time..

Comment: Without knowing how long max acceleration is done with more weight , it is not possible to guess except , it will be less

Comment: What is the dischare rate (C rate) of your battery?

Comment: Weight will affect how **far** you can go on a charge, among other things.

Answer (score 1):

Your battery has 48V*35Ah =1680 Wh energy stored, which is rated for a certain discharge rate, C/x.

If the motor is using its full power at 20kph of 200W then it should last 1680/200 =8.4 hr if this discharge rate matches the test condition for Ah rating. If it is rated at a  C/10 condition (168W)  then the run time using 200 W will be less. Without knowing the test rate and actual power drawn , you can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

> i want to know how weight will affect the running time

The energy required to accelerate an 80kg mass + body (say another 80kg) to a speed of 20kph is fairly easy to calculate.

Velocity is 20kph = 20,000/3600 metres per second = 5.6m/s
Total mass is 160kg and energy of that mass moving at 5.6m/s is: -

E = \$\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot M\cdot V^2\$ = 4938 joules.

Your battery is 48V and 35 Ah. Assuming you can utilize half that energy, the energy available is: -

\$\dfrac{48V \times 35A \times 3600s}{2}\$ joules = 6.048MJ

Assuming there is no drag, motor or friction losses, it seems to me you could start and stop 1224 times before the battery was no longer usable. Friction and drag take a big amount of energy but without knowing these I'm not going guess. I'd guess motor efficiency could be around 80%.